# Select Option not showing required fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to add some book name to issue book list through jquery.But I couldn't find the problem.Can anyone please help me?Moreover, jquery is running well.

jquery script code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        //department id dhorbo
        $("#department").change(function(){
            var depid = $("#department").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>manage/getBookByDepId/" + depid,
                success:function(data){
                    //book form maje show korbo
                    $("#book").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>manage/addIssueForm" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Departmant</label>
                <!-- <input type="text" name="dep" class="form-control span 12"> -->
                <select name="dep" id="department">
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    <?php 
                            foreach ($depdata as $ddata){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $ddata->depid; ?>">
                        <?php echo $ddata->depname; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Book Name</label>
                <select name="bookname" id="book" class="form-control span 12"></select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" clss= btn btn-primary value="Submit">
            </div>

        </form>
```

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` inside the success method return?

Comment: Where is `#department`? I do not see it in your HTML example, so your AJAX would never run. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hello, twisty.thnx for the suggestion but it still not works.added juqery, book department but still not works.console log not showing error.